# Palindrome Pattern matching from the list of string

Tags: python, regex, list, pattern-matching

one question regarding repeating pattern

I have:

```
import re

a = ['123', '121', '136']
pattern_variable = '[1-9][1-9][1-9]'

for i in a:
    match = re.match(pattern_variable,i)
    if match != None:
        print(i)
```

Now let's assume I want to get only 121 from a list or 535 or 737 whatever has first and third position the same. Do you have any idea how would i define this with pattern variable?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capturing group and a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):

```
r'([1-9])[1-9]\1'
```

If you want to make sure it's the whole string :

```
r'\A([1-9])[1-9]\1\Z'
```

Or that the 3 digits form one single number :

```
r'\b([1-9])[1-9]\1\b'
```

The last 2 regexen would prevent `4121` from matching `121`.

## Update

If you want to match `121` but not `111`, you could use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
import re

a = ['123', '121', '136', '1232', '111', '1a1']
pattern_variable = r'\b([1-9])(?!\1)[1-9]\1\b'

for i in a:
    match = re.match(pattern_variable,i)
    if match != None:
        print(i)

#=> 121
```

It means : a word boundary, a digit not followed by itself, another digit, the same digit as the first one and a word boundary :)

Comment: Hi, thank you. May I just ask one more thing. You pattern match 121, but does match 111 as well. How could i match anythin that has on first position 1 and 1 on third but anything than 1 in second? thanks

Comment: Thank you Eric, very interesting. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a backreference:

```
pattern_variable = r'([1-9])[1-9]\1'
```

Note you need to use a raw string literal, or you'd have to escape the `1` twice.

Besides, if you want to match the *whole* string, you need to add `$` at the end of the pattern since `re.match()` only anchors the match at the *start* of the string. Or, if you use Python 3.4 and newer, you may use `pattern_variable` regex with the [`re.fullmatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) method.